# Convert from GDA2020 to GDA94 using proj string in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, proj, gda2020

Following [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/349780/is-there-a-proj4-string-for-gda2020-epsg7844-that-we-use-to-transform-from-38/350769#350769), I was able to convert from GDA94 to GDA2020 using proj string (I'm using PostGIS).

Now is there a way to convert it back? I tried to invert the signs from @JasonD answer but it didn't work:

`+proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0.06155,-0.01087,-0.04019,0.0394924,0.0327221,0.0328979`

When I use the above string on the converted geometry the coordinates are not the same from what they were before the conversion.

Can someone advise how to do it?

Comment: GDA2020 is not a parameterized transformation, it is a NTv2 grid from ICSM https://www.icsm.gov.au/gda2020 have a read of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/310567/use-ntv2-grid-files-in-postgis-st-transform to use NTv2 gsb files in PostGIS.

Comment: The proj4 strings describe the projection, i.e., there is one string for GDA94 and one for GDA2020. Just exchange them.

Comment: @MichaelStimson That's not true. There are [coordinate frame and NTv2 grid files to convert between GDA94 and GDA2020](https://www.icsm.gov.au/datum/gda-transformation-products-and-tools).

Comment: How much different? If you don't have ellipsoid height values, you won't exactly 'round-trip.'

Comment: @mkennedy while it is true that there is a 7 parameter transformation that was introduced as a stopgap it doesn't take into account the gravity distortion which gives a slight difference in the coordinates. You can do an X, Y shift without having to bounce off ellipsoidal heights using the GSB. It all depends on how accurate you need to be, if your accuracy figure is more than 5 metres you could probably get away with using the coordinates interchangeably as the difference is 1-2 m E and 1.5-3 m N in UTM, if someone checks your result using the ICSM calculator you'd be disproved though.

Comment: @MichaelStimson Really? ICSM converter's description says that both the 7-parameter similarity tfm and the conformal grid replicate each other (excepting the ellipsoidal height support). You're right that the conformal and distortion grid is different, they say it's up to 0.5 m in certain places. 1-2/1.5-3 looks more like not doing any transformation between GDA94 and GDA2020.