# No coordinate change when reprojecting GDA2020 to GDA94?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, australia, gda2020

I'm trying to use QGIS to reproject GDA2020 UTM55 coords to GDA94 UTM55 (they were recorded GDA2020 because 2022 but now we need to put them into older software). I load the CSV into QGIS and run the reprojection tool but the coordinates come out exactly the same.

Shouldn't they be about 1.5m different?

I've read [Proj.4/GDAL/QGIS Transformation between CRSs that are defined the same](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/262281) which seems to talk about a similar thing but it's five years old now and it's a bit over my head.

I've tried the same conversion in ArcGIS and it comes out the same. I don't understand what's going to here.

Comment: Do you mean the coordinate values in your attribute table? Simply reprojecting will not update your attribute table. After running Reproject on your csv layer, either use the field calculator with expression `$x` and `$y` or use the 'Add geometry attributes' tool on the 'Reprojected' output layer to add the transformed GDA94 coordinates. You can then save back to a csv with the updated coordinate values if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

As per comments I had to use 'Add geometry attributes' to put the reprojected coordinates in the attribute table and only then export.